# How to get the list of domains from LDAP using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, dns, ldap

I am new to programming(VB.NET) and need help to get list of all Domain names from LDAP from my project.
I am able to retrieve other details like First Name, Surname, Mail, etc...but can't get list of domain names. I tried many options online but none worked for me. I just need the list of domains so I can loop it further and continue with other process.
Help would be much appreciated.

As of now I am using the below code :

```
dirEntry = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & " & Environment.UserDomainName & ")
dirSearcher = New System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
dirSearcher.Filter = "(&(GivenName=" & txt_First_Name.Text & ")(sn=" & txt_Family_Name.Text & "))"
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName")
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sn")
dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail")
Str_Searchres = dirSearcher.FindOne()
Dir_direntry = Str_Searchres.GetDirectoryEntry()
Str_Old_SGID = Dir_direntry.Properties("samAccountName").Value.ToString()
Str_SGID = txt_SGID.Text
Str_Fname = Dir_direntry.Properties("GivenName").Value.ToString()
Str_Lname = Dir_direntry.Properties("sn").Value.ToString()
Str_Mail = Dir_direntry.Properties("mail").Value.ToString()
```

**Environment.UserDomainName** gives me my domain, but I need all the domains available in LDAP.
Help would be appreciated.

Best Regards,